# ConnectionResetError [Errno 54] TCP connection, trying to request and receive a file from the server but client end is delayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, python-multithreading

Overall, I'm running a UDP connection and then connecting clients over TCP. I want the tcp client to ask the tcp server(another client) for a file, send it, and download it. It seems the sender is fine, but the receiver isn't fully receiving the file or throws an exception and then receives the total file after some time and then the exception:
I keep going back and worth with whether the receiver should be in a while loop but I'm trying to account for any size file to be sent. Any thoughts? TIA.

```
Exception in thread Thread-5 (file_receiving_thread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/App.py", line 205, in file_receiving_thread
    data = s.recvfrom(4096)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
< Connection with client A closed. >
```

```
def file_receiving_thread(s, fileName):
    print(f"< Downloading {fileName} ... >")
    
    with open(f'downloaded_{fileName}', 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            data = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if not data:
              break
            f.write(data[0])
    print(f'< {fileName} downloaded successfully! >')
   


# given a file and a dir, this checks if file is in dir
def is_file_in_dir(file_path, dir_path):
    for file_name in os.listdir(dir_path):
        if file_name == os.path.basename(file_path):
            return True
    return False

  
def file_sender_thread(tcp_conn, tcp_client_address, requested_file_name_decoded):
  global my_dir_path
  global myTbl

  # check if requested file exists
  file_name_path_before_abs = os.path.join(my_dir_path, requested_file_name_decoded)
  absolute_file_name_path = os.path.abspath(file_name_path_before_abs)
  if not is_file_in_dir(absolute_file_name_path, my_dir_path):
    print(f"< {requested_file_name_decoded} not found in directory {my_dir_path} >")
    tcp_conn.close()
    return

  ## send file
  try:
    with open(requested_file_name_decoded, 'rb') as f:
      print(f'< Transferring {requested_file_name_decoded}... >')
      while True:
        data = f.read()
        if not data:
          break
        tcp_conn.send(data)
    print(f'< {requested_file_name_decoded} transferred successfully! >')
        
  except FileNotFoundError:
    tcp_conn.sendall(b'File not found')
    print(f'File not found: {requested_file_name_decoded} ({tcp_client_address})')
    


#thread to listen for connections from other clients and SEND file
def tcp_listen_for_thread(my_tcp_port):
    
    tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_socket.bind(('localhost', my_tcp_port))
    tcp_socket.listen()

    while True:
        # Wait for a new client connection
        tcp_conn, tcp_client_address = tcp_socket.accept()
        print(f"< Accepting connection request from {tcp_client_address[0]} >")

        requested_file_name = tcp_conn.recvfrom(4096)
        requested_file_name_to_decode = requested_file_name[0]
        requested_file_name_decoded = requested_file_name_to_decode.decode()

        # go to file sender thread 
        file_to_send_thread = threading.Thread(target=file_sender_thread, args=(tcp_conn, tcp_client_address, requested_file_name_decoded,))
        file_to_send_thread.start()
        file_to_send_thread.join()
        tcp_conn.close()
        print(f'< Connection with client ____ closed. >')


#thread to connect to other clients and REQUEST their file
def tcp_talk_thread(fileName, fileOwner, owners_tcp_IP, owners_tcp_port,):
  
    with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((owners_tcp_IP, owners_tcp_port))
        print(f"< Connection with client {fileOwner} established. >")
        s.sendall(fileName.encode())
        # go to file receiver thread
        file_to_receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=file_receiving_thread, args=(s, fileName,))
        file_to_receive_thread.start()
        file_to_receive_thread.join()
    s.close()
    print(f'< Connection with client {fileOwner} closed. >')
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP is stream-oriented, not message-oriented.  It is just a stream of bytes, it has no concept of message boundaries, like UDP does.

The receiver is reading in the file data in an endless loop until either:

- the sender closes the connection
- the connection fails

The sender is closing the connection after sending the file's data, but there is no guarantee that the receiver will detect that closure if something else unexpected happens to cause the connection to fail prematurely.

A better design choice is to have the sender send the file's size first, then send the file's data.  The receiver can then read in the size first, and then read in only as many bytes as the size specifies.  Don't use connection closure as a success indicator.  Treat an unexpected closure as a transfer failure.

You should do that same thing when sending the file's name too, for that matter (really, for any kind of variable-length data).  Send the file name's length before sending its characters, and then read in the length first and then read in only the specified number of characters.

---

Also, there is no point in creating a worker thread just to immediate `join` it after `start`'ing it, that is a complete waste of a worker thread.